# If an Ethereum wallet address can't receive Bitcoin why do I have Bitcoin in it?

Tags: myetherwallet

When I visit MyEhtereumWallet.com and view whats in my Ethereum address/wallet, it shows I have a small amount of BTC in it. How/why?

Because of seeing this I tried sending BTC to that Ethereum address and of course it didn't work. I don't know how I got the BTC in there in the first place. I think it might be left over from buy TheDao Tokens before May 28th (i.e. not on an exchange). Is there some otherway to get BTC into my Ethereum address/wallet?

I like the security of me controlling my wallet and not relying on some BTC wallet hosting company.

Comment: What makes you think its BTC?

Comment: I think you see the equivalent value of your ETH in BTC, not that there are bitcoins...

Answer (score 2):

After multiple requests from our users, MyEtherWallet displays the equivalent value of the ETH held in USD, EUR, BTC, etc. However, we could certainly make it clearer that that is what we are showing.